# angularjs ui route error coming from other html link

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, anchor

I created an html file and make an anchor tag. 
`<a href="http://localhost:8888/#/product" target="_blank">product</a>`

I want to make the angular app open in `http://localhost:8888/#/product` but it reloads to `http://localhost:8888/#/`.

What can I fix in my angular app to allow that kind of url opening in new tab? Thank you.

Comment: It should *just work* ™

Answer (score 0):

with ui-router you can use ui-sref="stateName" to change view.

Here's an example:

```
<a ui-sref="routeHere" target="_blank">A Link</a>
```

**Note:** you can only open a new tab with:

> target="_blank"

only if you use an anchor tag along with ui-sref.

more info here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

Answer (score 0):

Use AngularJS Routing to accomplish it.

If you want to navigate to different pages in your application, but you also want the application to be a SPA (Single Page Application), with no page reloading, you can use the ngRoute module.

The ngRoute module routes your application to different pages without reloading the entire application.

Example:
Navigate to "red.htm", "green.htm", and "blue.htm":

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

<p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

<a href="#red">Red</a>
<a href="#green">Green</a>
<a href="#blue">Blue</a>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>
  var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
  app.config(function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
   .when("/", {
     templateUrl : "main.htm"
   })
   .when("/red", {
     templateUrl : "red.htm"
   })
   .when("/green", {
     templateUrl : "green.htm"
   })
   .when("/blue", {
      templateUrl : "blue.htm"
    });
 });
</script>
```

To make your applications ready for routing, you must include the AngularJS Route module:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Then you must add the ngRoute as a dependency in the application module:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
```